# error: redeclaration of enumerator for contiki os libtomcrypt library

Tags: c, rsa, public-key-encryption, contiki

I am working on encryption in CONTIKI OS and COOJA simulator which i tired to use the library libtomcrypt. I include the library into CONTIKI folder but when i tired to call the rsa_make_key function it given me this error. Thanks in advance and hope to heard from you guys soon.

```
> make TARGET=cooja clean 
rm -f *~ *core core *.srec \
    *.lst *.map \
    *.cprg *.bin *.data contiki*.a *.firmware core-labels.S *.ihex *.ini \
    *.ce *.co
rm -rf 
rm -rf obj_cooja

> make sender-node.cooja TARGET=cooja 
  CC        sender-node.c
In file included from ../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt.h:80:0,
                 from sender-node.c:43:
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:4:4: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'PK_PUBLIC'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:4:4: note: previous definition of 'PK_PUBLIC' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:5:4: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'PK_PRIVATE'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:5:4: note: previous definition of 'PK_PRIVATE' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:16:4: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'PKA_RSA'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:16:4: note: previous definition of 'PKA_RSA' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:17:4: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'PKA_DSA'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:17:4: note: previous definition of 'PKA_DSA' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:20:16: error: redefinition of 'struct Oid'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:20:16: note: originally defined here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:24:3: error: conflicting types for 'oid_st'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:24:3: note: previous declaration of 'oid_st' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:26:5: error: conflicting types for 'pk_get_oid'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:26:5: note: previous declaration of 'pk_get_oid' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:32:16: error: redefinition of 'struct Rsa_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:32:16: note: originally defined here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:51:3: error: conflicting types for 'rsa_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:51:3: note: previous declaration of 'rsa_key' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:53:5: error: conflicting types for 'rsa_make_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:53:5: note: previous declaration of 'rsa_make_key' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:55:5: error: conflicting types for 'rsa_get_size'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:55:5: note: previous declaration of 'rsa_get_size' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:57:5: error: conflicting types for 'rsa_exptmod'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:57:5: note: previous declaration of 'rsa_exptmod' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:61:6: error: conflicting types for 'rsa_free'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:61:6: note: previous declaration of 'rsa_free' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:80:5: error: conflicting types for 'rsa_encrypt_key_ex'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:80:5: note: previous declaration of 'rsa_encrypt_key_ex' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:85:5: error: conflicting types for 'rsa_decrypt_key_ex'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:85:5: note: previous declaration of 'rsa_decrypt_key_ex' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:91:5: error: conflicting types for 'rsa_sign_hash_ex'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:91:5: note: previous declaration of 'rsa_sign_hash_ex' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:98:5: error: conflicting types for 'rsa_verify_hash_ex'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:98:5: note: previous declaration of 'rsa_verify_hash_ex' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:104:5: error: conflicting types for 'rsa_sign_saltlen_get_max_ex'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:104:5: note: previous declaration of 'rsa_sign_saltlen_get_max_ex' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:107:5: error: conflicting types for 'rsa_export'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:107:5: note: previous declaration of 'rsa_export' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:108:5: error: conflicting types for 'rsa_import'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:108:5: note: previous declaration of 'rsa_import' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:170:16: error: redefinition of 'struct Dh_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:170:16: note: originally defined here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:174:3: error: conflicting types for 'dh_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:174:3: note: previous declaration of 'dh_key' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:178:5: error: conflicting types for 'dh_get_size'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:178:5: note: previous declaration of 'dh_get_size' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:180:5: error: conflicting types for 'dh_make_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:180:5: note: previous declaration of 'dh_make_key' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:181:6: error: conflicting types for 'dh_free'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:181:6: note: previous declaration of 'dh_free' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:183:5: error: conflicting types for 'dh_export'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:183:5: note: previous declaration of 'dh_export' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:184:5: error: conflicting types for 'dh_import'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:184:5: note: previous declaration of 'dh_import' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:186:5: error: conflicting types for 'dh_shared_secret'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:186:5: note: previous declaration of 'dh_shared_secret' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:189:5: error: conflicting types for 'dh_encrypt_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:189:5: note: previous declaration of 'dh_encrypt_key' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:194:5: error: conflicting types for 'dh_decrypt_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:194:5: note: previous declaration of 'dh_decrypt_key' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:198:5: error: conflicting types for 'dh_sign_hash'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:198:5: note: previous declaration of 'dh_sign_hash' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:202:5: error: conflicting types for 'dh_verify_hash'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:202:5: note: previous declaration of 'dh_verify_hash' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:241:3: error: conflicting types for 'ltc_ecc_set_type'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:241:3: note: previous declaration of 'ltc_ecc_set_type' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:253:3: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_point'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:253:3: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_point' was here
In file included from ../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt.h:80:0,
                 from sender-node.c:43:
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:271:3: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:271:3: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_key' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:274:31: error: conflicting types for 'ltc_ecc_sets'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:274:31: note: previous declaration of 'ltc_ecc_sets' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:278:6: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_get_size'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:278:6: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_get_size' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:280:6: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_make_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:280:6: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_make_key' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:281:6: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_make_key_ex'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:281:6: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_make_key_ex' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:282:6: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_free'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:282:6: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_free' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:284:6: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_export'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:284:6: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_export' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:285:6: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_import'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:285:6: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_import' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:286:6: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_import_ex'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:286:6: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_import_ex' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:288:5: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_ansi_x963_export'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:288:5: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_ansi_x963_export' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:289:5: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_ansi_x963_import'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:289:5: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_ansi_x963_import' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:290:5: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_ansi_x963_import_ex'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:290:5: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_ansi_x963_import_ex' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:292:6: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_shared_secret'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:292:6: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_shared_secret' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:295:6: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_encrypt_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:295:6: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_encrypt_key' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:300:6: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_decrypt_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:300:6: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_decrypt_key' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:304:5: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_sign_hash_raw'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:304:5: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_sign_hash_raw' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:308:6: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_sign_hash'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:308:6: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_sign_hash' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:312:5: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_verify_hash_raw'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:312:5: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_verify_hash_raw' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:316:6: error: conflicting types for 'ecc_verify_hash'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:316:6: note: previous declaration of 'ecc_verify_hash' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:321:12: error: conflicting types for 'ltc_ecc_new_point'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:321:12: note: previous declaration of 'ltc_ecc_new_point' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:322:12: error: conflicting types for 'ltc_ecc_del_point'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:322:12: note: previous declaration of 'ltc_ecc_del_point' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:328:5: error: conflicting types for 'ltc_ecc_projective_dbl_point'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:328:5: note: previous declaration of 'ltc_ecc_projective_dbl_point' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:331:5: error: conflicting types for 'ltc_ecc_projective_add_point'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:331:5: note: previous declaration of 'ltc_ecc_projective_add_point' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:349:5: error: conflicting types for 'ltc_ecc_mulmod'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:349:5: note: previous declaration of 'ltc_ecc_mulmod' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:353:5: error: conflicting types for 'ltc_ecc_mul2add'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:353:5: note: previous declaration of 'ltc_ecc_mul2add' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:369:5: error: conflicting types for 'ltc_ecc_map'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:369:5: note: previous declaration of 'ltc_ecc_map' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:403:3: error: conflicting types for 'dsa_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:403:3: note: previous declaration of 'dsa_key' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:405:5: error: conflicting types for 'dsa_make_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:405:5: note: previous declaration of 'dsa_make_key' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:406:6: error: conflicting types for 'dsa_free'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:406:6: note: previous declaration of 'dsa_free' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:408:5: error: conflicting types for 'dsa_sign_hash_raw'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:408:5: note: previous declaration of 'dsa_sign_hash_raw' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:412:5: error: conflicting types for 'dsa_sign_hash'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:412:5: note: previous declaration of 'dsa_sign_hash' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:416:5: error: conflicting types for 'dsa_verify_hash_raw'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:416:5: note: previous declaration of 'dsa_verify_hash_raw' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:420:5: error: conflicting types for 'dsa_verify_hash'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:420:5: note: previous declaration of 'dsa_verify_hash' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:424:5: error: conflicting types for 'dsa_encrypt_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:424:5: note: previous declaration of 'dsa_encrypt_key' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:429:5: error: conflicting types for 'dsa_decrypt_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:429:5: note: previous declaration of 'dsa_decrypt_key' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:433:5: error: conflicting types for 'dsa_import'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:433:5: note: previous declaration of 'dsa_import' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:434:5: error: conflicting types for 'dsa_export'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:434:5: note: previous declaration of 'dsa_export' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:435:5: error: conflicting types for 'dsa_verify_key'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:435:5: note: previous declaration of 'dsa_verify_key' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:437:5: error: conflicting types for 'dsa_shared_secret'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:437:5: note: previous declaration of 'dsa_shared_secret' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:445:14: error: nested redefinition of 'enum ltc_asn1_type_'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:445:14: error: redeclaration of 'enum ltc_asn1_type_'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:445:14: note: originally defined here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:447:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_EOL'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:447:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_EOL' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:448:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_BOOLEAN'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:448:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_BOOLEAN' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:449:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_INTEGER'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:449:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_INTEGER' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:450:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_SHORT_INTEGER'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:450:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_SHORT_INTEGER' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:451:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_BIT_STRING'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:451:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_BIT_STRING' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:453:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_OCTET_STRING'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:453:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_OCTET_STRING' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:454:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_NULL'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:454:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_NULL' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:455:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_OBJECT_IDENTIFIER'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:455:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_OBJECT_IDENTIFIER' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:456:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_IA5_STRING'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:456:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_IA5_STRING' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:457:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_PRINTABLE_STRING'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:457:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_PRINTABLE_STRING' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:459:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_UTF8_STRING'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:459:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_UTF8_STRING' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:460:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_UTCTIME'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:460:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_UTCTIME' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:461:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_CHOICE'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:461:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_CHOICE' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:462:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_SEQUENCE'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:462:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_SEQUENCE' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:463:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_SET'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:463:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_SET' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:465:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_SETOF'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:465:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_SETOF' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:466:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_RAW_BIT_STRING'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:466:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_RAW_BIT_STRING' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:467:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_TELETEX_STRING'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:467:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_TELETEX_STRING' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:468:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_CONSTRUCTED'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:468:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_CONSTRUCTED' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:469:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'LTC_ASN1_CONTEXT_SPECIFIC'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:469:2: note: previous definition of 'LTC_ASN1_CONTEXT_SPECIFIC' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:473:16: error: redefinition of 'struct ltc_asn1_list_'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:473:16: note: originally defined here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:484:3: error: conflicting types for 'ltc_asn1_list'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:484:3: note: previous declaration of 'ltc_asn1_list' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:497:5: error: conflicting types for 'der_encode_sequence_ex'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:497:5: note: previous declaration of 'der_encode_sequence_ex' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:502:5: error: conflicting types for 'der_decode_sequence_ex'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:502:5: note: previous declaration of 'der_decode_sequence_ex' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:507:5: error: conflicting types for 'der_length_sequence'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:507:5: note: previous declaration of 'der_length_sequence' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:515:5: error: conflicting types for 'der_decode_subject_public_key_info'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:515:5: note: previous declaration of 'der_decode_subject_public_key_info' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:522:5: error: conflicting types for 'der_encode_set'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:522:5: note: previous declaration of 'der_encode_set' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:525:5: error: conflicting types for 'der_encode_setof'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:525:5: note: previous declaration of 'der_encode_setof' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:533:6: error: conflicting types for 'der_decode_sequence_flexi'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:533:6: note: previous declaration of 'der_decode_sequence_flexi' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:535:6: error: conflicting types for 'der_sequence_free'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:535:6: note: previous declaration of 'der_sequence_free' was here
In file included from ../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt.h:80:0,
                 from sender-node.c:43:
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:624:5: error: conflicting types for 'der_decode_choice'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:624:5: note: previous declaration of 'der_decode_choice' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:638:3: error: conflicting types for 'ltc_utctime'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:638:3: note: previous declaration of 'ltc_utctime' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:640:5: error: conflicting types for 'der_encode_utctime'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:640:5: note: previous declaration of 'der_encode_utctime' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:643:5: error: conflicting types for 'der_decode_utctime'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:643:5: note: previous declaration of 'der_decode_utctime' was here
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:646:5: error: conflicting types for 'der_length_utctime'
../../../core/./../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt_pk.h:646:5: note: previous declaration of 'der_length_utctime' was here
make: *** [sender-node.co] Error 1
Process returned error code 2
```

This is the part where i tired to call the functionprng_state* prng;

```
 prng_state* prng;
  rsa_key* key;
  int result = rsa_make_key(
    prng,
    0,
    rsa_get_size(key),
    65537,
    key);
```

I had also include the tomcrypt.h for the library in the code

```
#include "../apps/libtomcrypt/src/headers/tomcrypt.h"
```

Comment: Is this the *only* header you included?

Comment: yes for libtomcrypt library. The rest of the include is inside tomcrypt.h. this is the list of include inside #include "tomcrypt_cfg.h"
#include "tomcrypt_macros.h"
#include "tomcrypt_cipher.h"
#include "tomcrypt_hash.h"
#include "tomcrypt_mac.h"
#include "tomcrypt_prng.h"
#include "tomcrypt_pk.h"
#include "tomcrypt_math.h"
#include "tomcrypt_misc.h"
#include "tomcrypt_argchk.h"
#include "tomcrypt_pkcs.h"
#include "tomcrypt_pk.h"

Comment: Yes, I've visited the github page for it. That's why I asked. Only the top level header (`tomcrypt.h`) is meant to be included. I personally feel the author could have added a few `#error` directives to safe guard against it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that either `tomcrypt.h` or `tomcrypt_pk.h" file gets included several times and that therefore the same things get defined several times.

To try out if this is the reason, I'd add the following lines at the top and at the end of `tomcrypt.h`, respectively.

At the top:

```
#ifndef _TOMCRYPT_H
#define _TOMCRYPT_H
```

At the end:

```
#endif
```

Repeat this for `tomcat_pk.h`:

```
#ifndef _TOMCRYPT_PK_H
#define _TOMCRYPT_PK_H
...
#endif
```

If the code then compiles, then the problem is that the same header file gets included (directly or indirectly) more than once in a compilation unit may also apply to other header files, e.g. `tomcrypt_pk.h`. So you could also check if you incude, for example, `tomcrypt_pk.h` directly in your `.c`-file, while another header file (e.g. `tomcrypt.h`) also includes this file.

If this is the case, you have two principal ways of solving the problem: (1) remove unnecessary include statements, (2) protect the include file from being interpreted more than once, e.g. by surrounding the definitions by `#ifndef - #define`-statements. I'd prefer option (1) over option (2).

Note that - as pointed out by StoryTeller - it is not encouraged to edit third party library files, even not for introducing such `#ifndef-#define`-statements. If you cannot manage to follow option (1), you could still surround the respective `#include`-statements in your files, e.g.

```
// in myFile.c:
#ifndef _TOMCRYPT_PK_H
#define _TOMCRYPT_PH_H
#include "tomcrypt_pk.h"
#endif
```

Comment: #ifndef _TOMCRYPT_H
#define _TOMCRYPT_H its already been add in tomcrypt.h when i download the library

Comment: Hm - what's about `tomcrypt_pk.h`? Does this file contain such a protection?

Comment: no it does not have that so i just add #ifndef _TOMCRYPT_PT_H
#define _TOMCRYPT_PT_H  right?

Comment: @lol - Modifying library headers is usually a bad idea. Most likely your project has an include for one of the headers which aren't meant to be included.

Comment: @StoryTeller The main reason i think i had this problem is that i need to used the function rsa_make_key and rsa_get_size which is in tomcrypt_pk.h but i don't see it include inside tomcrpyt.h and i got undefined error so i include tomcrypt_pk.h myself. Is that a bad idea to do that?

Comment: @lol - yes. When I viewed the source [on github](https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt/blob/develop/src/headers/tomcrypt.h) it was clear that `tomcrypt_pk.h` is included in `tomcrpyt.h`.

Comment: @StoryTeller and stephan lechner thanks for the help i include the file twice by accident Thanks alot

Comment: @StoryTeller: you are right; editing library files is usually a bad idea; it was more meant as a technique for remotely finding out what the problem is :-)